# Calling unknown method: yii\db\Command::select()

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

help me please, i will take some data from table with substring, but show this error.

```
Calling unknown method: yii\db\Command::select()
```

this my code:

```
<table>
       <thead>
           <td>Permission</td>
           <td>Status</td>
           <td>Remove</td>
       </thead>
        <tbody>
       <?php  
        $a = Yii::$app->db->createCommand()->select('name as item')->from('auth_item')->query();
        foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
        $c = $a.substring(1);
       ?>
          <td><?php echo $c ?></td>
          <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: Like explained in the [Guide](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-query-builder) you should use Query Builder for that.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is only fetching data.
`Yii::$app->db->createCommand()` is mostly used for insert & update case.

You can try following code -

```
use yii\db\Query;
$query = new Query();
$query->select('name as item')->from('auth_item')->orderBy('created_at');
$command = $query->createCommand();
$records = $command->queryAll();
// print_r($records); // expected results
```

[Quick Simplified other option here](http://www.bsourcecode.com/yiiframework2/select-query-sql-queries/) and [detailed docs](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-query-builder)

Answer (score 0):

pass variable in where clause yii2

```
 $query = new Query();


$query = new Query();
$query->select('mail')
->from('table') 
->where(['column'=>$cond_1, 'column2' => 'cond_2']);
$command = $query->createCommand();
$record= $command->queryAll();
$email = $record[0]['mail'];
```